# AutoCAD References Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, autocad, autodesk

I'm currently trying to use c# to develop some programs to help automate AutoCAD, but I am not able to use Visual Studio due to not being able to afford Enterprise or Professional, and Community is giving me "Access not allowed" errors on any program I run. Thus, I am trying to use Visual Studio Code, but am having trouble getting the proper references in. I've tried using Nuget and installing all the Autodesk/AutoCAD search results, but none have worked. According to the .NET AutoCAD Developer's Guide, I need to reference .dll's called "AcMgd.dll", "AcDbMgd.dll", and "AcCoreMgd.dll" but they do not come up on the Nuget search. How can I get these properly set up so I can develop AutoCAD? Is it possible, or will I need to find a way to use Visual Studio?
Below are imports I am trying to use and corresponding errors.

Thanks!

[image: imports attempting to use]

[image: corresponding errors]

Comment: Just an FYI: This website has little to no support for Autodesk products. You might want to look at the web forums at Autodesk websites instead.

Comment: All these solutions bellow uses Visual Studio IDE not VSCode:
If you want to start develop a AutoCAD Plugin, in-process concept, follow my answer at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469179/console-app-in-c-sharp-fails-to-execute-as-soon-as-data-types-in-autodesk-librar/56416934#56416934)
Else if needs to drive AutoCAD out-of-process, follow this another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159304/how-to-export-dwg-files-to-images-using-autocad-api-with-c/56433836#56433836) Else all these links not understandable, response me here.

Answer (score 2):

Those files, AcMgd.dll, AcDbMgd.dll, and AcCoreMgd.dll will located in the directory that AutoCAD is installed to. They will have to be added as a reference normally, through the browse button, not through Nuget.

I just noticed you said VS Code. I do not know how you have the project setup or how to add references, but you have to reference those files specifically.

You should also make sure that when you add those as a reference that the "Copy Local" is set to false.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set it up in .csproj file.

```
<Reference Include="AcMgd">
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD xxxx\acmgd.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="AcDbMgd">
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD xxxx\AcDbMgd.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="AcCoreMgd">
  <HintPath>C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD xxxx\AcCoreMgd.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

General .csproj example you can find here:
https://github.com/cake-build/example/blob/master/src/Example/Example.csproj

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Enterprise or Professional version of any application or any Nuget package to do what you're trying to do. All the necessary .dll files are already available on your system if you have already installed AutoCAD application correctly. I am assuming you have the AutoCAD license with you.

**Downloading and installing necessary files for AutoCAD Development**

- Download Autodesk AutoCAD SDK from the link ([www.autodesk.com/developautocad](https://www.autodesk.com/developautocad/)) and run it to install the necessary software development kit created by Autodesk. Go to the link above and scroll down and find **Managed .NET** and download `ObjectARX SDK` for the correct version of autocad that you are using.

**Creating a new Visual Studio Project**

- Open Visual Studio (Community Edition will work perfectly fine.)
- Create a new project by selecting `WPF Custom Control Library (.NET Framework)`.

**Setting up Visual Studio project to target AutoCAD**

- Go to `Solution Explorer` > Select the project file > `Right Click` > `Properties`

  ***On Debug Tab***
- Start action > Start external program > `Browse` and select AutoCAD application `acad.exe` from your local machine.
- Start options > Command line arguments > input `/nologo`

  ***On References Tab***
- Folder > Browse > Add reference files from `C:/Autodesk/AutoCAD_ObjectARX_2019_Win_64_and_32_Bit/inc/` Folder.
- Save and Close `Properties` window

***Adding necessary AutoCAD references/Libraries***

- Go to `Solution Explorer` again > `Right Click` References > Add Reference > Browse to the folder where AutoCAD is installed in your local machine and add these references: *AcCoreMgd.dll, AcDbMgd.dll and AcMgd.dll*
- Assuming you followed all the steps correctly, you have now set-up your development environment successfully.
- Now, you can start writing your code to develop logic for your AutoCAD API.
- When you will debug/run(`F5`) your code, you will notice AutoCAD automatically opens on your system.
- You can then load the .dll file in autoCAD by using `NETLOAD`.

**Loader Lock exception**

- You might encounter Loader Lock exception while first time executing the program. To resolve this on visual studio go to: `Debug menu > Windows > Exception Settings > Managed debugging assistants >  Uncheck Loader lock`

I hope this helps!! All the best.